# Replace NaN values in all levels of a Pandas MultiIndex

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan, multi-index

After reading in an excel sheet with a MultiIndex, I am getting np.nan appearing in the index because some of the values are 'N/A' and pd.read_excel thinks it's a good idea to convert them.  However I want to keep them as 'N/A' to preserve the multi-index.  I thought it would be easy to change them back using [MultiIndex.fillna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.fillna.html) but I get this error:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[u'foo', u'bar'], [u'one', np.nan]],
           codes=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=[u'first', u'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=['A', 'B'])
df
```

[image]

```
df.index.fillna("N/A")
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-09e14dcdc74f> in <module>
----> 1 df.index.fillna("N/A")

/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py in fillna(self, value, downcast)
   1456         fillna is not implemented for MultiIndex
   1457         """
-> 1458         raise NotImplementedError("isna is not defined for MultiIndex")
   1459 
   1460     @Appender(_index_shared_docs["dropna"])

NotImplementedError: isna is not defined for MultiIndex
```

**Update:**

Code updated to reflect Pandas 1.0.2. Prior to version 0.24.0 the `codes` attribute of `pd.MultiIndex` was called `labels`.  Also, the traceback details changed from `isnull is not defined` to `isna is not defined` as above.

Comment: This is a kind of solution I guess: `new_index = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[index.levels[0].fillna('N/A'), index.levels[1].fillna('N/A')],
           labels=index.labels,
           names=index.names)` but my actual dataframe is a 6-level MultiIndex so it's bit messy!

Comment: I would suggest to load the dataframe without any index hint, massage the NA stuff, then set_index. Any reason you could not proceed in that order?

Comment: Thanks @Boud that would also work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accepted solution did not work for me either. It still left NA values in the index even though inspecting the `df.index.levels` individually did not show NA values.

Jorge's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61037402) pointed me in the right direction but also wasn't quite right for my case. Here is my approach, including handling of the single `Index` case as discussed in the comments of the accepted answer.

```py
if isinstance(df.index, pd.MultiIndex):
    df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
        df.index.to_frame().fillna(my_fillna_value)
    )
else:
    df.index = df.index.fillna(my_fillna_value)
```

Comment: I tested the previously accepted solution by @piRSquared today and indeed it doesn't seem to work (see my comment).  This one and Jorge's both work and I decided to accept this one because it addresses my original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use `set_levels`

```
df.index.set_levels([l.fillna('N/A') for l in df.index.levels], inplace=True)
df
```

[image]

Comment: OP has 6-levels! Update the answer to fix all levels in one shot?

Comment: @NehalJWani Updated post, fully generalized.  Thanks

Comment: :-o Didn't know that set_levels supported a List in its argument!

Comment: @NehalJWani, why not? It just needs an iterable. I am guessing a dict will also work, with the keys being converted to level names. Haven't tried it though.

Comment: I'm getting an error when i use this: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-439020707a4b> in <module>()
      1 #replace nans in index
----> 2 df.index.set_levels([l.fillna('N/A') for l in df.index.levels], inplace=True)
      3 
      4 df

AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'set_levels'

Comment: @FistOfFury your attempting to use this on a single level, otherwise known as a normal, index.  In that case, you just do something like df.index = df.index.fillna('N/A')

Comment: There are some issues with this solution (see @totalhack's answer). I assume it worked back in 2016 or I wouldn't have accepted it but anyway, now if I do this it doesn't seem to change the index. Strangely, after executing your code, the values in level 2 of the index are different though: `df.index.levels[1].values` gives `array(['one', 'N/A'], dtype=object)` but `df.index[1]` gives `('foo', nan)`.

Answer (score 3):

The current solution didn't work for me when having multi level columns. What i did and worked for me was the following:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.columns.to_frame().fillna(''))
```